# WPF 3D Camera confusion

Tags: wpf, xaml, 3d, camera

I am working on a flooring visualizer (for a tile floor in perspective) and am going bonkers over the camera.  Basically, I have a 2D rectangle (on the X & Y axis) and I want to look at the square as if it were a floor (which I'll "tile" later - similar to a checkerboard).
The problem is, after spending hours fiddling with the LookDirection and Position (in the perspective camera), I can't seem to get it to look straight at the square (as if looking into the room). Nothing I change allows me to look at the scene "head on" (with either the X or Y axis in the "back") and it's always stuck at an angle.  I don't want to rotate the model, only the camera.
How do I do this?

```
        <Viewport3D>
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera Position="-40,60,50" LookDirection="0.8,-.7,-0.8"  UpDirection="0,0,1" />
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <Model3DGroup>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="-1,-1,-3" />
                    <GeometryModel3D>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                            <MeshGeometry3D Positions="0,0,0 25,0,0 25,25,0 0,25,0 " TriangleIndices="0 1 3 1 2 3  "/>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <DiffuseMaterial Brush="Red"/>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                    </GeometryModel3D>
                </Model3DGroup>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
    </Viewport3D>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're stuck at an angle because of your `LookDirection`. This is a direction vector, so having `X`, `Y`, and `Z` set is going to give you that offset look. You're pointing off into space at an angle rather than straight ahead. To look straight ahead, set `X` to 0 in your `LookDirection` and instead move the camera's `Position X` to the center of your scene, which is 12.5 (because your square goes from 0 to 25).

```
<PerspectiveCamera Position="12.5,60,50" LookDirection="0,-.7,-0.8"  UpDirection="0,0,1" />
```

That will produce a "head on" view. Based on what you said, it seemed like you wanted to be closer to the "floor", so I moved the `Position` closer to the "floor" and reduced the angle on the `LookDirection` vector, like so.

```
<PerspectiveCamera Position="12.5,50,20" LookDirection="0,-.7,-0.35"  UpDirection="0,0,1" />
```

This produced the following.
[image]

Comment: So the camera position is based on the size of the largest object and Z axis is up/down (not in/out). I guess that makes more sense now (a movable camera icon in VS would be a godsend, if not just for getting your 3D bearings straight).

Comment: @MC9000 Yeah, think of the camera as an object in your scene. The `Position` coordinates are going to be relative. The Z axis is up/down because you set `UpAxis` to (0,0,1). If you're more comfortable with Z being in/out, set `UpAxis` to (0,1,0) and then the Y axis will be your up/down. I agree that VS doesn't have good tools for working in 3D space. You're pretty much stuck mentally visualizing your scene. Good luck!